# Oracle sql developer - connection 'xe' does not exist?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle 11g express and sql developer. When I open SQL developer, I don't see any connection called 'xe'. When I try to create a connection with name = xe, user name = xe, some password and role == sysdba, 
I get an error -

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Why is this happening and how can I see 'xe' ? How do I create a connection with sysdba privileges ?

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure a connection in connection-menu in sql-developer:

[image]

You can right-click it, choose `properties` and that's what you'll get is probably the following  basic settings screen:

[image]

Or, you might need to configure the connection using the "advanced settings":

[image]

No need to mention that the username/password is case-sensitive.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I appreciate that you did so much to help me. But, I dont see anything on the left pane of above windows in my copy of sql developer. In fact, when I open it, all i see is a small button cor connections and no actual connections. If I try to make any connection, I get the error i mentioned in my post. How do I fix this ?

Comment: UPDATE - I right-clicked "connections button" and chose "create local connections". This created a folder called "auto-generated local connections" under "connections button". Now that folder contains some connections one of which is system-XE. But, I still don't see a 'xe' that I used to see before.

Comment: Now that you can see a connection in the connections panel, right-click it and follow my explanation above.

Comment: Yes, it works. I can create a connection using the system-xe connection. I choose a name for my connection but not for username. The username has to remain the default value, ie 'system'. Why is this so ? If i change the username to something else, I get the error mentioned in my post.

Comment: The reason for that is that it won't save the session if you failed to login. Try to change the `roll` to `default`